# El uso de "parece" o "parece ser"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Me interesa cuál de las siguientes posibilidades es mejor o más correcta. ¿Se escribe "me parece difícil" o "me parece ser difícil"?

Answer (score 2):

Como dicen todos, lo correcto es

> Me parece difícil

Para ver por qué, es mejor no omitir sujetos.

Puedes decir `Eso me parece difícil`, `Eso parece difícil` o `Eso parece ser difícil`.

¿Por qué no la otra? ¿Por qué no `Eso me parece ser difícil`?

La respuesta es que, al incluir el complemento indirecto, estamos rompiendo la unión `parece ser`, que actúa como si fuera una especie de "verbo único".

El complemento indirecto no deja duda de que `parecer` se emplea como verbo principal. Entonces `ser difícil` sería atributo, y no es apropiado que una forma impersonal haga referencia a un pronombre "eso", por muy neutro que sea.

Sí puedes decir `Eso me parece que es difícil`, porque `que es difícil` sí es un atributo válido (proposición subordinada sustantiva), porque el pronombre "que" lo enlaza con el sujeto "Eso".

Comment: Buena respuesta. Usaríamos la otra construcción en situaciones como _parece ser difícil comprar un piso últimamente_.

Answer (score 0):

"Me parece difícil" es para mi la forma correcta o la más apropiada.

He escuchado las formas "Me parece **que es**" y "me parece **que esta**"  para usar los verbos ser y estar

Pero rara vez he escuchado "Me parece ser", aunque no tengo ningún argumento para descalificarla pues a su vez tendría concordancia con "**Me parece estar**" y si he escuchado ese tipo de construcciones, pero sin el "**Me**"

> **Parece ser** y **Parece estar**

Tal vez dependa de la región o del estilo propio de comunicarse de cada quien.